# How to display current date and time in power bi visuals?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Is it possible to add a card in power BI that shows the current date and tome  time??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can show ***only*** time of last data refresh. Use one of this:

1. DAX Measure 
      MyNow = TODAY()
      returns single date
2. PowerQuery
      MyNow = DateTime.LocalNow()
      returns table with single row & col

Comment: The DAX measure updates with every report refresh, the M-formula with the data refresh. Only in PowerBI Desktop these things happen at the same time. However, this was not the question. I guess it's not possible to show the current date and time in a visual and it doesn't make much sense either.

Answer (score 1):

Current Date & Time:

```
MyCurrentDateAndTime := NOW()
```

The value will be updated each time you open the file.

Comment: Does this apply to Power BI or Excel? Question is about Power BI.